# Python multiprocessing pipe recv() doc unclear or did I miss anything?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I have been learning how to use the Python multiprocessing module recently, and reading the official doc.  In [**16.6.1.2. Exchanging objects between processes**](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) there is a simple example about using pipe to exchange data.

And, in [**16.6.2.4. Connection Objects**](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#connection-objects), there is this statement, quoted "Raises **EOFError** if there is nothing left to receive and the other end was closed."

So, I revised the example as shown below.  IMHO this should trigger an **EOFError** exception: nothing sent and the sending end is closed.

The revised code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    #conn.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    #print parent_conn.recv()   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    try:
        print parent_conn.recv()
    except EOFError:
        pass
    p.join()
```

But, when I tried the revised example on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine, Python 2.7.2, the script hang.

If anyone can point out to me what I missed, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Please remove the "or has bug". The probability of a bug is nearly zero.  Focus on the likely explanation -- misread or unclear documentation.

Comment: @S.Lott, you were right.  It's my oversight - not a bug at all. Forgot about Python's reference counting, and the best practice of using duplex pipes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you start a new process with `mp.Process`, the child process inherits the pipes of the parent. When the child closes `conn`, the parent process still has `child_conn` open, so the reference count for the pipe file descriptor is still greater than 0, and so EOFError is not raised.

To get the EOFError, close the end of the pipe in both the parent and child processes:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo_pipe(conn):
    conn.close()

def pipe():
    conn = mp.Pipe()
    parent_conn, child_conn = conn
    proc = mp.Process(target = foo_pipe, args = (child_conn, ))
    proc.start()
    child_conn.close()  # <-- Close the child_conn end in the main process too.
    try:
        print(parent_conn.recv())
    except EOFError as err:
        print('Got here')
    proc.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    pipe()
```

Comment: Verified in python 3.8, too. There is only one pipe (bidirectional) between the child and his parent, with two ends. Closing child_conn does not delete the pipe. EOFError is only raised when the pipe is empty (if the child has not sent anything), and child_conn is closed from both sides. If not closed from parent's side and pipe empty, parent_conn.recv() waits... Even if child_conn is closed on both sides, this variable still exists in pipe() (its reference count is not 0), but the parent has nothing to expect from the child, so EOFError.

Comment: The result is the same if foo_pipe() does not close the connection. In summary, EOFError is when the child sends nothing, and the parent closes the child connection before receiving.